# Unable to successfully instantiate BreakIterator even after u_setDataDirectory was set

Tags: c++, icu

I am using ICU's `BreakIterator` (icu 68.2) for word segmentation.
I have used `u_setDataDirectory` to initialise the data path as mentioned in below code snippet's 1st line.
But when I check the status of `createWordInstance()`, I am getting `U_MISSING_RESOURCE_ERROR`. This kind of error should be solved by calling `u_setDataDirectory`. I have used that, but the problem is still there.

```
u_setDataDirectory;
UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
BreakIterator *wordIterator = BreakIterator::createWordInstance(Locale("zh"), status);

if (U_FAILURE(status)) 
{
   std::cout<<"failed to create break iterator.  status = "<<u_errorName(status)<<std::endl;
   exit 1;
}
UnicodeString text = "sample input string";
wordIterator->setText(text);
delete wordIterator;
```

Comment: from [documentation](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/dev/icu4c/classicu_1_1BreakIterator.html#a50cefbc6dfc4eae78e926f4604c3d63c) : "To check whether the construction succeeded or not, you should check the value of U_SUCCESS(err). "

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number: You are right. I am getting U_MISSING_RESOURCE_ERROR as the status. But I have no clue why this is so.

Comment: Edited the heading to reflect the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If u_setDataDirectory is the only cause for your error, you must call it with the correct path to the data directory.

change your first line from

```
 u_setDataDirectory;
```

to (on Linux/Unix)

```
 u_setDataDirectory( "/path/to/ICU/data/" );
```

or on Windows to

```
 u_setDataDirectory( "C:\\Path\\To\\ICU\\Data\\" );
```

Unfortunately I don't know where are the data files of ICU. You need to correct the path string to the correct path on your system.

But from the reading of the ICU documentation https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/dev/icu4c/putil_8h.html#a550ea8502df5fed47ae4359be7f8e6a2
I guess, this is not enough to solve your problem.

If the call above does not solve your problem, you can try to call u_init( UErrorCode *status ) as the very first statment:

```
UErrorCode status = U_ZERO_ERROR;
u_init( &status );
if (U_FAILURE(status)) 
{
   std::cout<<"failed to init. status = "<<u_errorName(status)<<std::endl;
   std::exit( 1 );
}
```

and then check what is the problem.

**EDIT**
A second root cause can be that the "Locale("zh")" is missing.
Does it work with other locales? Like change it to "en_US" ?

You can also test if the Locale works by this:

```
if( Locale("zh").isBogus() )
{
    std::cout << "Locale is not working!" << std::endl;
    std::exit( 1 );
}
```